# Haskell/GHC: Polymorphic character literals

Tags: haskell, ghc

Is there a GHC language extension I can use to get polymorphic character literals? Like `OverloadedStrings` but for characters?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would you want that for?

Comment: @DanielFischer: In the [Google Code Jam Caeser cypher problem](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/1460488/dashboard) I used two different `newtypes` to wrap `Char`s to represent encyphered and plain text (to prevent mixing them).  But I needed to bounds check both. [See my `derive` function to see where the class would have been handy](https://github.com/rampion/GoogleCodeJam/blob/master/SpeakingInTongues.hs).

Comment: passing a reified character conversion function is not such a bad thing imo, but you could always wrap that into a typeclass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: No, there isn't. Not yet, at least.